# Exception was thrown at line 101, column 217 in jquery-1.4.4.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012

Using Internet Explorer 11.0.1 / Visual Studio Update 4

Simply running a project where jquery-1.4.4.min.js is referenced within the  section, results in this error being displayed in the output window: Exception was thrown at line 101, column 217 in jquery-1.4.4.min.js    0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

There does not appear to be any other adverse affect on the page but am curious as to the cause of the error, thanks in advance for any insight.

Ok, in response to some comments on the old version of jQuery being used for this project I updated the script to version 1.10.2. Unfortunately the number of errors expanded to 3 after this change.

1. Exception was thrown at line 1639, column 4 in jquery-1.10.2.js
2. Exception was thrown at line 1656, column 4 in jquery-1.10.2.js
3. Exception was thrown at line 1274, column 6 in jquery-1.10.2.js

All with : 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

I am working on capturing the un-minified section of code along with with some more debugging information from the console. Will post this a little later...thanks.

Update:
Hi all, it appears that the issue has something to do with html tags. In the MVC view being used the top tag is `<!DOCTYPE html>` and then a little further down in the view is a `<html>` tag. For some reason jQuery thinks this is two html tags. The other exceptions are related to table tags, I have a `<body>` tag in the view and a `<tbody>` tag in the table and a `<head>` tag in the view and a `<thead>` tag in the table. This accounts for the three exceptions being thrown. There does not appear to be any adverse affect outside of the thrown exceptions but it does appear quite odd. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use a 4 year-old version of `jQuery` ?

Comment: IE11 was launched long after 1.4.4, my guess is 1.4.4 has a bug in IE11.

Comment: Step 1 in debugging javascript is to include a non-minified version of the code that is failing so that you can actually see what line it is failing on.

Comment: @Cristy The old version of jQuery was applied as part of a nuget package for jQuery DataTables, this is the version that is included by default with the package. I have since updated the version of jQuery being used in the application to version 1.10.2. I will edit the question to include the error now being shown.

Comment: I don't think the problem is jQuery misinterpreting the doctype declaration. You probably have invalid HTML somewhere else. Removing the doctype will only make the browser enter quirks mode and therefore behave differently. Have you tried validating your HTML: validator.w3.org ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the F12 tools. You should see the exception logged to the console. You can then click on the link in the console to go to the line. Even if it is minimized it will take you to the problem point. Look for the {} icon in the debug tab. This will 'pretify' the minimized code so you can set a break point. This will help you find the error. But I agree with the comment above you need to upgrade jQuery to either 1.9.x or 2.x. Most likely it is a bug caused by browsers upgrading a lot since 2009.